# Adobe Acrobat Reader doesn't print my drawing on a PDF

Tags: pdf, printing, adobe

I have written and drawn some figures and text on my PDF but in my preview when printing, or when I print the PDF, it doesn't come out with the text and figures on the PDF. I have tried the options "forms and comments" and also "print as image" but this doesn't work. 
how did I make the figures? In the comment tab you can add a comment, highlight stuff and add Text and Figures I have also drawn stuff on my tablet using another app, but this also shows in Acrobat Reader, so shouldn't be a problem. 
What can I do to make sure All of it prints??

example of drawing on PDF lecture slide:

[image: example of drawing on PDF lecture slide]

Comment: Can you share a sample pdf with that issue?

Answer (score 0):

In the print dialog, be sure that "Document and Markups" is selected in the dropdown just above the preview window. The default is just to print the just Document.

[image: Print Dialog]