# Acrobat nor any other pdf viewer won't print connected line annotations

Tags: pdf, acrobat

Similar to this problem, however the solution does not work.
[Adobe Acrobat Reader doesn't print my drawing on a PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43235422/adobe-acrobat-reader-doesnt-print-my-drawing-on-a-pdf)

I use a [Boox Max Carta](https://onyxboox.com/boox_max-carta) to write and annotate pdf works.
The annotations are exported from the e-reader as pdf annotations (comments) of the category connected lines.

[Here is an example file.](https://1drv.ms/b/s!AlXtG4WyYXTmgZ1xzrWnk2dB6doy6A)

When I go to print, if I select Document and markup - I get nothing.

If I select summarise comments then I get numbers for each annotation but no scribble.

[image: Pdf Print annotation failure]

### What do I need to do to print annotated pdfs?

Is there a way to flatten it into an image or something?

### Solution - Thanks to @mkl for finding the root cause

Use the Python PyMuPdf library to loop through the pages and annotations adding a flag to each of them.

```py
""" Recipies used
https://pymupdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq/#how-to-search-for-and-mark-text
https://pymupdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq/#how-to-add-and-modify-annotations
"""

import sys
import fitz
fname = sys.argv[1]                    # filename
doc = fitz.open(fname)
updated_annot_count = 0;
for page in doc:       
    current_annot = page.firstAnnot;                # scan through the pages
    while current_annot:
        current_annot.setFlags(current_annot.flags|fitz.ANNOT_XF_Print)
        current_annot = current_annot.next          # Follow linked list
        updated_annot_count = updated_annot_count+1


if doc:
    doc.save("printable-" + doc.name)
```

[The Pdf renders fine on the computer screen in both Chrome and Adobe Acrobat (2017)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S9EPy.png)

Comment: If Adobe Acrobat can't load them properly, that's typically your sign that whatever _exported_ the PDF has document-breaking bugs, and you probably want to take this up with Onyx. Did you check to see if there's a fixed firmware?

Comment: Acrobat does load them properly (See the example file). I just cannot print the connected lines

Comment: I see a complete mess of boxes, so I don't think you're using the word "properly" correctly. If there was supposed to be more content then the document is broken, because Acrobat is literally the gold standard for rendering PDF documents. If there's something in it that Acrobat doesn't render, then the document is not following the PDF specification.

Comment: Google Chrome and Acrobat render them absolutely fine on my PC. I've edited the orig question with an example of how they are rendered for me

Comment: That has become a much better explanation. I'd also recommend removing that "dummy file" picture, because what matters is what you're running into, and the propert description of that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All of the line drawing annotations (actually there are annotations of type **Line**, **Square**, **Polygon**, and **PolyLine**) have *no* **F**lags entry; thus, their annotation flags value defaults to 0, all flags cleared.

> **F**
>   integer
>   *(Optional; PDF 1.1)* A set of flags specifying various characteristics of the annotation (see 12.5.3, “Annotation Flags”). Default value: 0.

*(ISO 32000-1, Table 164 – Entries common to all annotation dictionaries)*

In particular the **Print** flag is cleared.

> 3
>   **Print**
>   (PDF 1.2) If set, print the annotation when the page is printed. If clear, never print the annotation, regardless of whether it is displayed on the screen.

*(ISO 32000-1, Table 165 – Annotation flags)*

So your annotations explicitly are created to *not be printed ever*.

If you want to print them nonetheless, set the **Print** flag of your annotations.

This should be a simple task to implement using any general purpose PDF library.